# Java: how to sum element of an array one by one in the same array

Tags: java

I´ve searched and thought about it a lot but can´t come up with a solution.

Given an array of numbers, I should sum each element with the next and write it in the same array, then again and again until the first position [0] of the array contains the sum of all elements.
For example: `test[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
next step would be:
`test[0] = test[0] + test[1] = 1 + 2 = 3;`
`test[1] = test[2] + test[3] = 3 + 4 = 7;`
`test[2] = test[4] = 5;`
array becomes: {**3**, **7**, **5**, 4, 5}

then it repeats again:
`test[0] = test[0] + test[1] = 3 + 7 = 10;`
`test[1] = test[3] = 5;`
array becomes: {**10**, **5**, 5, 4, 5}

then finaly again:
`test[0] = test[0] + test[1] = 10 + 5 = 15;`
array becomes: {**15**, 5 , 5, 4, 5}

I know that a List would be the right solution but the exercise is to solve it with a simple array. 
All suggestions are more then welcome!

Again: this task is not about efficency but about solving it using arrays. 
Sorry this is my first post and it looks a mess.

**Edit:**
What i´ve have come up to is this:
`for (int i = 0; i < test.length - (test.length / 2); i++) {
     test[i] = test[2 * i] + test[2 * i + 1];
}`
but it works only incase of an even amount of given numbers and it needs to be in a loop to be repeated the correct ammount of times.

Comment: For the first element, what do you do? For the second element what do you do? For the last element what do you do?

Comment: `test[0] += test[i]` in some sort of loop

Comment: Can you use multiple arrays?  Something like `A2[0] = A1[0] + A2[1]...`

Comment: Given an array of numbers I have to:
test[0] = test[0] + test[1];
test[1] = test[2] + test[3];
test[2] = test[4] + test[5];  then i have to repeat the process until the summ of all elements is on test[0]

Comment: test[0] = test[0] + test[1] = 1 + 2 = 3;
test[1] = test[2] + test[3] = 3 + 4 = 7;
Now that all pairs has been added, repeat the process:
test[0] = test[0] + test[1] = 3 + 7 = 10;

Comment: @user3795167 What if the array is test[] = {1,2,3,4,5}?

Comment: About the case of an uneven amount of number is not told. I guess it is part of the problem because, it would be even on the second cicle, uneven in the third cicle, then even again etc..

Comment: Wouldn't it be `t[0] = t[0] + t[1],t[1] = t[1] + t[2],...`?  In which case your first pass would result in `{3,5,7,<no clue about the fourth>}`/

Comment: @Andrew On your second pass you'd be summing things multiple times

Comment: I´ve edited the question and hopefully made it more clear. Thanks all four your help.

Comment: Check out the solution I just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is messy, but works. It modifies the array in place, each time overwriting half(summed up) of the array, with odd amounts being kept in-place.

```
int[] test = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int l = test.length;
do {
    l = sumTo(test, l);
} while (l > 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
```

sumTo takes two arguments, the array to be modified, and the index to sum to.

```
int sumTo(int[] ar, int to) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < to; i += 2) {
        if (i == to - 1)
            ar[i / 2] = ar[i];
        else
            ar[i / 2] = ar[i] + ar[i + 1];
        }
    return (i + 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: I can confirm it works! now i have to understand how xD

Comment: the variable l/to is the amount of the array that we sum each time. Each iteration, you divide the array in half, rounding up. When there's only a single element left, that's the sum of the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double f = test.length;
for(int j =0; j<=(int)(Math.log(f)/Math.log(2));j++){ //here i want the exponent
    int q = (int)Math.ceil(f/Math.pow(2,j)); //simplified because it's calculated once
    for (int i = 0; i<q; i+=2){
        if(i<q-1){
           test[i] += test[i+1];
           test[i/2] = test[i];
        else{
           test[i/2] = test[i];
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: This task is not about efficiency but about solving it by just using an array.

Your solution just adds all elements on the first one but it is not what the tasks asks for. I have to add all elements in pair then again and again until i have the total sum on position [0].

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Useful for a file merge. Give me a second and I'll fix what I have, I've done this before.

Comment: Would make me happy :)

Comment: Sorry jhobbie but with an imput of {1,2,3,4} your final array is {10, 7, 7, 4} when it should be {10, 7, 3, 4}.

Comment: So close. Well, if you step through it with debugger, you should be able to make a modification and get it right

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] tab = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
    tab[0] += tab[1];
    tab[1] = tab[2]+tab[3];
}
```

That could match to your description.